# Infinite reboot loop and black screen after Windows 10 update but keyboard still works

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have a Dell XPS 8920 Desktop, and after the latest Windows Update I get a black screen. There is no splash logo or anything - the screen is completely black at all times. When powered on the computer starts up, then I can hear after 17 seconds (I timed it) that it reboots, and the process repeats endlessly.

I've discovered that I can get into the BIOS screen if I press F12 as the computer's restarting. I can't see that I'm in BIOS because the screen stays black but it seems clear to me that I am, because I get predictable outcomes by pressing certain keys (e.g. if I press F10 to save and exit the BIOS, I can hear the computer make a restarting noise). However, restoring the BIOS to factory defaults doesn't fix anything.

I'm not sure if this is purely because of the update, or whether perhaps the computer lost power during the update. I have some reason to suspect that the computer lost power during the update.

Comment: Try booting Windows media and repair.  If the update was interrupted it's very likely that is the cause.

Comment: I do have a Windows USB I can use for that but the problem is that I can't see what I'm doing because the screen is black. By copying the keyboard presses needed on another computer I managed to change the boot mode so it boots from a Windows USB. However, I still can't see the screen so I don't know what to do at this next stage.

Comment: @user1205197 Have you tried connecting a monitor to the on-board HDMI or DisplayPort ports?

Comment: [Follow-up](https://superuser.com/q/1488983/154126) from the OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it plausible that an interrupted Windows update can cause the motherboard to fail?](https://superuser.com/questions/1488983/is-it-plausible-that-an-interrupted-windows-update-can-cause-the-motherboard-to)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia More like a dupe. This question should have been modified to add the details from that question. Since that question got traction and activity, I will attempt to add content from this question to that one. This should be closed.